# trigger a function after a while django python

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, task

I use django for a project. Users can make exchanges. If one user places an order with another and the second user accepts. I would like that after 24 hours if the order is not processed by the seller it is canceled. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you can use a background task scheduler like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/)
after order placed put a task with 24 hour delay to run 24 hour after that time to check if exchange is completed or not

Comment: I have learn about celery. I read the docs but I don't understand. Have you any tutorial ?